# transactional email not triggered

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

[image]
Above is my cron setting from admin.
My email transactional emails suddenly stopped working couple of days back. it was delaying email sending since I upgraded to Magento version 1.9.2.3 since then I am facing this issue. I have Already Added AOE Scheduler and all my crons look fine. it was working but has suddenly stopped since a couple of days

I installed SMTP pro. but now my Emails are sent to spam except of inbox

Comment: @fschmengler I have tried these solutions. Aoe Scheduler is installed all cron look fine. I dont have cpanel to check server how to check it via ssh if my cron is properly set up on server

Comment: @HarshadaChavan, you can verify your cron job using `crontab -l` ssh command.

Comment: where do I run this command? in the server root directory or magento root?

Answer (score 0):

Its due to the changes made in magento order notification flow. First check, is it only for order confirmation or for all, try to update the status and check whether you received the email or not. if you receive the email then follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450413/magento-1-9-1-0-order-confirmation-emails-not-sending
you just need to change the code $mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send(); to $mailer->send(); at public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php location. don't  make it directly follow the rewrite steps to rewrite this one.

Comment: its not just order, New registrations also do not receive any email confirmation

Comment: create one simple php file which includes core mail functionality and place this in a root directory then execute this one and check whether mail is working  or not as this may be a mail issue of your server. let me know if you still have a problem or not.

Comment: Malandkar I checked email from root and it triggers email perfectly. so its not from server end. is there any issue with my cron settinng? I have attached a screen shot above

Comment: can you please share your url .

Comment: I added that SMTP pro plugin it started worknig but now emails are going in spam